# jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox Very Slow With Large Select Lists

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I'm using a modified version of the jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox, as seen here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

*For the sake of this question, let's say I have exactly that code ^^^*

When opening the combobox, either by clicking the button or focusing on the comboboxs text input, there is a large delay before showing the list of items. This delay gets noticeably larger when the select list has more options.

This delay doesn't just occur the first time either, it happens every time.

As some of the select lists on this project are very large (hundreds and hundreds of items), the delay/browser freezing up is unacceptable.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction to optimise this? Or even where the performance problem may be?**

I believe the issue may be to do with the way the script shows the full list of items (does an autocomplete search for an empty string), is there another way to display all items? Perhaps I could build a one off case for displaying all items (as it is common to open the list before starting to type) that doesn't do all the regex matching?

Here is a jsfiddle to fiddle with:
http://jsfiddle.net/9TaMu/

Comment: you would probably see the biggest speed increases by doing all of regex and manipulation before the widget is created so only simple array/object lookups are performed when the widget is being used.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

With the current combobox implementation, the full list is emptied and re-rendered every time you expand the dropdown. Also you are stuck with setting the minLength to 0, because it has to do an empty search to get the full list.

Here is my own implementation extending the autocomplete widget.  In my tests it can handle lists of 5000 items pretty smoothly even on IE 7 and 8. It renders the full list just once, and reuses it whenever the dropdown button is clicked. This also removes the dependence of the option minLength = 0. It also works with arrays, and ajax as list source. Also if you have multiple large list, the widget initialization is added to a queue so it can run in the background, and not freeze the browser.

```
<script>
(function($){
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", $.ui.autocomplete, 
        {
        options: { 
            /* override default values here */
            minLength: 2,
            /* the argument to pass to ajax to get the complete list */
            ajaxGetAll: {get: "all"}
        },

        _create: function(){
            if (this.element.is("SELECT")){
                this._selectInit();
                return;
            }

            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this);
            var input = this.element;
            input.addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            this.button = $( "<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
            .insertAfter( input )
            .button({
                icons: { primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
            .click(function(event) {
                // close if already visible
                if ( input.combobox( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                    input.combobox( "close" );
                    return;
                }
                // when user clicks the show all button, we display the cached full menu
                var data = input.data("combobox");
                clearTimeout( data.closing );
                if (!input.isFullMenu){
                    data._swapMenu();
                    input.isFullMenu = true;
                }
                /* input/select that are initially hidden (display=none, i.e. second level menus), 
                   will not have position cordinates until they are visible. */
                input.combobox( "widget" ).css( "display", "block" )
                .position($.extend({ of: input },
                    data.options.position
                    ));
                input.focus();
                data._trigger( "open" );
            });

            /* to better handle large lists, put in a queue and process sequentially */
            $(document).queue(function(){
                var data = input.data("combobox");
                if ($.isArray(data.options.source)){ 
                    $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, data.options.source);
                }else if (typeof data.options.source === "string") {
                    $.getJSON(data.options.source, data.options.ajaxGetAll , function(source){
                        $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, source);
                    });
                }else {
                    $.ui.combobox.prototype._renderFullMenu.call(data, data.source());
                }
            });
        },

        /* initialize the full list of items, this menu will be reused whenever the user clicks the show all button */
        _renderFullMenu: function(source){
            var self = this,
                input = this.element,
                ul = input.data( "combobox" ).menu.element,
                lis = [];
            source = this._normalize(source); 
            input.data( "combobox" ).menuAll = input.data( "combobox" ).menu.element.clone(true).appendTo("body");
            for(var i=0; i<source.length; i++){
                lis[i] = "<li class=\"ui-menu-item\" role=\"menuitem\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" tabindex=\"-1\">"+source[i].label+"</a></li>";
            }
            ul.append(lis.join(""));
            this._resizeMenu();
            // setup the rest of the data, and event stuff
            setTimeout(function(){
                self._setupMenuItem.call(self, ul.children("li"), source );
            }, 0);
            input.isFullMenu = true;
        },

        /* incrementally setup the menu items, so the browser can remains responsive when processing thousands of items */
        _setupMenuItem: function( items, source ){
            var self = this,
                itemsChunk = items.splice(0, 500),
                sourceChunk = source.splice(0, 500);
            for(var i=0; i<itemsChunk.length; i++){
                $(itemsChunk[i])
                .data( "item.autocomplete", sourceChunk[i])
                .mouseenter(function( event ) {
                    self.menu.activate( event, $(this));
                })
                .mouseleave(function() {
                    self.menu.deactivate();
                });
            }
            if (items.length > 0){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self._setupMenuItem.call(self, items, source );
                }, 0);
            }else { // renderFullMenu for the next combobox.
                $(document).dequeue();
            }
        },

        /* overwrite. make the matching string bold */
        _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
            var label = item.label.replace( new RegExp(
                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + 
                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>" );
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        },

        /* overwrite. to cleanup additional stuff that was added */
        destroy: function() {
            if (this.element.is("SELECT")){
                this.input.remove();
                this.element.removeData().show();
                return;
            }
            // super()
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.destroy.call(this);
            // clean up new stuff
            this.element.removeClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );
            this.button.remove();
        },

        /* overwrite. to swap out and preserve the full menu */ 
        search: function( value, event){
            var input = this.element;
            if (input.isFullMenu){
                this._swapMenu();
                input.isFullMenu = false;
            }
            // super()
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.call(this, value, event);
        },

        _change: function( event ){
            abc = this;
            if ( !this.selectedItem ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( this.element.val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                    match = $.grep( this.options.source, function(value) {
                        return matcher.test( value.label );
                    });
                if (match.length){
                    match[0].option.selected = true;
                }else {
                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                    this.element.val( "" );
                    if (this.options.selectElement) {
                        this.options.selectElement.val( "" );
                    }
                }
            }                
            // super()
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._change.call(this, event);
        },

        _swapMenu: function(){
            var input = this.element, 
                data = input.data("combobox"),
                tmp = data.menuAll;
            data.menuAll = data.menu.element.hide();
            data.menu.element = tmp;
        },

        /* build the source array from the options of the select element */
        _selectInit: function(){
            var select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            this.options.source = select.children( "option[value!='']" ).map(function() {
                return { label: $.trim(this.text), option: this };
            }).toArray();
            var userSelectCallback = this.options.select;
            var userSelectedCallback = this.options.selected;
            this.options.select = function(event, ui){
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                if (userSelectCallback) userSelectCallback(event, ui);
                // compatibility with jQuery UI's combobox.
                if (userSelectedCallback) userSelectedCallback(event, ui);
            };
            this.options.selectElement = select;
            this.input = $( "<input>" ).insertAfter( select )
                .val( value ).combobox(this.options);
        }
    }
);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Stellar! This really sped things up for me. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to use your implementation, as it's perfect, but when I tried it and clicked the button, nothing happens!  No menu appears!  The autocomplete still works though.  Any idea why?  Could it be because of an update to jquery ui?

Comment: @dallin the script above depended on jquery-ui 1.8.x, it needs some minor changes to work for 1.9.x.  It's been awhile since I last worked on it, but I've posted the code here 

https://github.com/garyzhu/jquery.ui.combobox  

I didn't thoroughly test it with the lastest jquery-ui, just fixed the obvious javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the solution. However, we have several issues with it. Not big ones, but though issues to solve. Do you have an updated version somewhere?

Comment: @gary or anyone can give jsfiddle link for the above solution?

Comment: I have just picked up minLength: 2, property, which simply solves the issue

Comment: i'm having difficulty with this code as well. Please add the markup and whatever init code is needed, even if it seems obvious. 

I added a <select id="combobox">, then in the last line of JS above the (jQuery), added
$("#combobox").combobox();
that gets the code started but it bombs out in document queue, because input.data("combobox") is null.

Comment: This is just great.

Answer (score 20):

I've modified the way the results are returned (in the **source** function) because the map() function seemed slow to me. It runs faster for large select lists (and smaller too), but lists with several thousands of options are still very slow.
I've profiled (with firebug's profile function) the original and my modified code, and the execution time goes like this:

> Original: Profiling (372.578 ms, 42307 calls)
>
> Modified: Profiling (0.082 ms, 3 calls)

Here is the modified code of the **source** function, you can see the original code at the jquery ui demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox. There can certainly be more optimization.

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    var select_el = this.element.get(0); // get dom element
    var rep = new Array(); // response array
    // simple loop for the options
    for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
        var text = select_el.options[i].text;
        if ( select_el.options[i].value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            // add element to result array
            rep.push({
                label: text, // no more bold
                value: text,
                option: select_el.options[i]
            });
    }
    // send response
    response( rep );
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is always return the same result set when using the same implementation for more than one drop down lists.

Comment: Perhaps the source code from jquery-ui has changed in the past 5 years but the "select.get(0);" needs to be "this.element.get(0);" to work.

Comment: Good answer, but the for loop must have `select_el.options.length` instead of `select_el.length`. I edited the code.

Comment: i replaced my "source:" line of code with this and my autocomplete didn't shown up even.

Answer (score 15):

I like the answer from Berro. But because it was still a bit slow (I had about 3000 options in select), i modified it slightly so that only first N matching results are displayed.
I also added an item at the end notifying the user that more results are available and canceled focus and select events for that item.

Here is modified code for source and select functions and added one for focus:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    var select_el = select.get(0); // get dom element
    var rep = new Array(); // response array
    var maxRepSize = 10; // maximum response size  
    // simple loop for the options
    for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
        var text = select_el.options[i].text;
        if ( select_el.options[i].value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            // add element to result array
            rep.push({
                label: text, // no more bold
                value: text,
                option: select_el.options[i]
            });
        if ( rep.length > maxRepSize ) {
            rep.push({
                label: "... more available",
                value: "maxRepSizeReached",
                option: ""
            });
            break;
        }
     }
     // send response
     response( rep );
},          
select: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( ui.item.value == "maxRepSizeReached") {
        return false;
    } else {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
        });
    }
},
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( ui.item.value == "maxRepSizeReached") {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Comment: Of course the solutions given are different, but your's gave the best performance. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome solution. I went ahead and extended the _renderMenu event of autocomplete because with AutoPostback dropdowns in asp.net it postback.

Comment: @iMatoria Praveen sir, Today i made some changes in your added file also nice to see you on this post too...and your Jquery work in Audit Expense is just great...Currently i'm working on it and learning a lot with your written code..:).. Thanks for giving me chance to work here..But unfortunately you have left from here...Learning Would be More immense if you were here ... :)

Comment: I get an error here with something calling tolower()? Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: Hi Peja, Your solution worked for me but after multiple time searches and clicked on combo box it freezing again the browser any idea?

Comment: This was the fastest solution i could get working! 
got an error on select_get(0), fixed by replacing with

var select_el = this.element.get(0); // get dom element

Answer (score 11):

We found the same thing, however in the end our solution was to have smaller lists!

When I looked into it it was a combination of several things:

**1) The contents of the list box is cleared and re-built every time the list box is shown** (or the user types something in and starts to filter the list).  I think that this is mostly unavoidable and fairly core to the way the list box works (as you need to remove items from the list in order for filtering to work).

You could try changing it so that it shows and hides items in the list rather than completely re-constructing it again, but it would depend on how your list is constructed.

The alternative is to try and optimise the clearing / construction of the list (see 2. and 3.).

**2) There is a substantial delay when clearing the list**.  My theory is that this is at least party due to every list item having data attached (by the `data()` jQuery function) - I seem to remember that removing the data attached to each element substantially sped up this step.

You might want to look into more efficient ways of removing child html elements, for example [How To Make jQuery.empty Over 10x Faster](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/how-to-make-jquery-empty-over-10x-faster/).  Be careful of potentially introducing memory leaks if you play with alternative `empty` functions.

Alternatively you might want to try to tweak it so that data isn't attached to each element.

**3) The rest of the delay is due to the construction of the list** - more specifically the list is constructed using a large chain of jQuery statements, for example:

```
$("#elm").append(
    $("option").class("sel-option").html(value)
);
```

This looks pretty, but is a fairly inefficient way of constructing html - a much quicker way is to construct the html string yourself, for example:

```
$("#elm").html("<option class='sel-option'>" + value + "</option>");
```

See 
[String Performance: an Analysis](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/) for a fairly in-depth article on the most efficient way of concatenating strings (which is essentially what is going on here).

---

Thats where the problem is, but I honestly don't know what the best way of fixing it would be - in the end we shortened our list of items so it wasn't a problem any more.

By addressing 2) and 3) you may well find that the performance of the list improves to an acceptable level, but if not then you will need to address 1) and try to come up with an alternative to clearing and re-building the list every time it is displayed.

Surprisingly the function filtering the list (which involved some fairly complex regular expressions) had very little effect on the performance of the drop down - you should check to make sure that you have not done something silly, but for us this wasn't the performance bottlekneck.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! This gives me something to do tomorrow :)  I would LOVE to shorten the lists, I don't think a drop down list is entirely appropriate for a list that large, however I'm not sure this will be possible.

Comment: @elwyn - Let me know how it goes - This was one of those things that I really wanted to fix, but we just didn't have time to do.

Comment: so did anyone optimize anything other than what Berro posted ? :)

Answer (score 1):

What I have done I am sharing:

In the `_renderMenu`, I've written this:

```
var isFullMenuAvl = false;
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                        if (requestedTerm == "**" && !isFullMenuAvl) {
                            var that = this;
                            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                            });
                            fullMenu = $(ul).clone(true, true);
                            isFullMenuAvl = true;
                        }
                        else if (requestedTerm == "**") {
                            $(ul).append($(fullMenu[0].childNodes).clone(true, true));
                        }
                        else {
                            var that = this;
                            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

This is mainly for server side request serving. But it can used for local data. We are storing requestedTerm and checking if it matches with `**` which means full menu search is going on. You can replace `"**"` with `""` if you are searching full menu with "no search string". Please reach me for any type of queries. It improves performance in my case for at least 50%.