# How does JavaScript distinguish between objects?

Tags: javascript

I have wriiten

```
document.createElement("p");
document.createElement("p")
```

How does Javascript intepreter knows do distinct between those two?

**Id** ? ( what is the Js **property** )? maybe something **else** ?

Comment: AFAIK not id. It should not be set by this.

Comment: Are you asking about how it is implemented in the JavaScript interpreter (behind the scenes), or are you asking a practical question to solve a problem you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case:

```
document.createElement("p");
document.createElement("p")
```

the JavaScript runtime doesn't worry about the elements *at all*, because you didn't save the values returned.  They're thrown away.

If you had written,

```
var p1 = document.createElementById('p');
var p2 = document.createElementById('p');
```

well then you've got two separate variables, and so **you're** keeping track of the difference.

It's important to be aware that the JavaScript interpreter itself doesn't really care too much about your DOM nodes.  That's not really it's business. If you call methods and create objects, it's your problem to keep track of them.

Comment: I probably asked wrong... when i do this document.body.appendChild(firstp); and then again document.body.appendChild(firstp); - how does now he distinguish between them ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: What do you mean by *how does now he distinguish between them*?

Comment: When im adding 2 new same elemsnts to the dom . what is the identifier field  that distinguish them ? because ive read that in the command appendChild - if he exists already in the DOM so he MOVES IT. so im asking how dows he knows if he already in the DOM ( and if i have 2 ?) how does he distinguish  between 2 identical elements

Comment: If you put no identifier on the elements yourself (like an "id" value), then it doesn't.  Even if you do add "id" attributes, that's not the concern of the JavaScript interpreter. It does not care what you do with your DOM elements.

Comment: @Pointy , "If child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild moves(!!!) it from its current position to the new position (i.e. there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."---- my question is : lets say i have one '<p>' and later on i got from the server via AJAX another <p>.... now if im doing appendCHILD -  HOW DOWS HE KNOW WHICH <p> to MOVE????

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That probably depends on the implementation of the DOM. Typically, each node has an *internal* ID. But again, that depends on the implementation. The DOM standard only defines the *interface*.

Comment: @RoyiNamir See my answer at the bottom of the page. You should have mentioned your previous Question + comment chain. Others haven't read the previous messages.

Comment: @Pointy , aaaahhhhh !! that what i wanted to know. and like i asked in the main question :  WHAT IS THE PROPERTY ID ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: There is nothing like a property ID. It is **internal**, something the implementation uses to keep track of node instances. Using IDs is just one way, there might be others. The DOM only defines *what* should happen, but not necessarily *how*. E.g. the definition for `appendChild`: *"Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed."*. So it just says that if `newChild` is in the tree, it has to be removed. It does not describe how the implementation should identify nodes.

Comment: @FelixKling  , I understand that but what about the case which HE DOESNT have a name like newChild ? e.g. Im adding nameless <p>... how can he track that ( if im adding another <p> later) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `newChild` is not a name a node has. It is just used as a descriptive name in the specification and actually refers to a node *reference*. FWIW, a DOM node is much more than just a tag. `<p>` is a tag, but the parser converts it to a DOM node. Some nodes don't even have a tag, like text nodes or comments. Maybe you have to become [more familiar with the DOM first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction).

Comment: @FelixKling , I know that newChild is a referrer to a node reference.I think you misunderstood me. If i add newChild to the Dom and then again - so of course he can track this because it has a reference. I talked about a situtation which im adding UNREFERENCED elements like document.body.appendChild('<p>'); If im doing this TWICE , how can he distinguish between them. thas my question

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `document.body.appendChild('<p>');` will throw an error. You have to pass a node reference. How do you get one? With `document.createElement`. Now, I don't know how this method is implemented (because there might be different implementations), but I assume this is where the "magic" happens and the returned node, although not added to the tree, has some identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Let's pick another real-life example: How does a human distinguish one orange from another one, in a basket? *I look inside the basket, and notice that there're multiple orange-coloured, ball-shaped items*

The JavaScript interpreter *internally* keeps track of the created objects. When an object isn't referred by anything (variables), the built-in Garbage Collector destroys the object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild  "If child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild moves(!!!) it from its current position to the new position (i.e. there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."---- my question is : lets say i have one '<p>' and later on i got from the server via AJAX another <p>.... now if im doing appendCHILD - HOW DOWS HE KNOW WHICH <p> to MOVE????

Comment: If you're requesting `appendChild` on a `<p>` element, you're referring to it. Say, you're holding a tomato. If someone else throws a new tomato at you, you're still able to say *"This is the tomato I was holding."*, because you knew that you were holding *that* tomato.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't.  createElement returns the object reference but if you don't assign it to anything or directly use it, it's lost.

```
var firstp = document.createElement("p");
var secondp = document.createElement("p");
```

Then you can assign an id or whatnot:

```
firstp.id = "first";
```

Keep in mind though, that this is not in the DOM yet.  You have to insert it somewhere before it can be seen by the user/found with getElementById.

For that you can do something like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(firstp);
```

Comment: Who downvoted this?  It's a perfectly good answer (to a fairly weird question).

Comment: thank you, @Pointy. idk what the downvoter saw wrong... I'd kind of like to know actually.

Comment: @Joseph , I probably asked wrong... when i do this document.body.appendChild(firstp); and then again document.body.appendChild(firstp); - how does now he distinguish between them ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. When you call `document.createElement()`, you create an element and it's inserted into the DOM. JavaScript can then grab certain `p` elements by ID, for example, or grab other `p` (and other) elements with `getElementsByClassName()`.

If you'd assigned the returned values to variables, you'd be able to keep track of which one was which by referencing different variables. This is *you* distinguishing between them, not JavaScript, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to them by their index in the array of elemnts:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
```

You can assign id to them

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id = 'first'
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].id = 'second'
```

And refer to them by id

```
document.getElementById('first')
```

It is up to you how you do it really...

Comment: -snip- sorry... misread that as `document.createElements('div')[1]`

Comment: will not be undefined if there are `div`s in the dom - and I assume that there is more code - and that the elements are actually being inserted in the dom. I don't think the question is about how to insert elements, but how to reference them later - so maybe by stored variable, or maybe by looking it up in the dom - the question is vague on this matter.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Yes, the question could use some more detail :P

Comment: And maybe another semi-colon (or one less) - the inconsistency is driving me mad