# Sort table by text, date and price when you click on the <th>

Tags: javascript, html

I need sort table by clicking on headers. I can use **only native js**.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Date of Birth</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
 </tr>
```

*First Name* (John) - sort text.
*Date* (23 Jul 1984) - sort date.
*Salary* ($69000) - sort number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to say with native js ? .. not pluggins ?
you can check posted in question [Sort a table fast by its first column with Javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558182/sort-a-table-fast-by-its-first-column-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/qNwDe/][1]

Comment: then :P this is your answer :)

Comment: Ok, thank you. And how I can sort by the Date (in 23 Jul 1984 format)?

Comment: You will need read values and add to array and converto to Date Javascript Object here you found a excelent example http://onpub.com/index.php?s=7&a=109

Answer (score 0):

You Can try [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) . It can sort based on the Tables header, and has other options too, checkout the examples in the site.