# Sort Table by date with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a date column (dd/mm/yyyy).  I want to sort the table rows by date on the click of a button with jquery.  I know there are several questions similar to this on here but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I think because of the format of my date.

Here is the page https://beabetteryou.com/course-dates/

Thanks

Comment: Unless you want to make this functionality yourself for some particular reason, there are plenty of table-sort jQuery plugins. Look for some and try them out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a table fast by its first column with Javascript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558182/sort-a-table-fast-by-its-first-column-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery table sorter plugin in the end as suggested by Jhecht. 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html