# JQuery UI Autocomplete load data on scroll

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have JQuery UI Autocomplete widget for my search bar, It works fine with me.Basically I want to load more data on scrolling of searchbar results, I have limited 100 results like pagination we do from backend.

I want to load more 100 results on scroll to end (like in pagination page 2 clicked will show 100 more results) and append to the list generated by autocomplete.  How do I achieve this, Is there any plugin available or some link that can help me. 
I have hight of 400px for search bar result. I have used Jquery.

I have found some solutions but that works with scrolling to the page end. Here I have search result with 400px height and scrollbar and would like to load more data on scrolling to last LI.

Help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

you can check this Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/EVsye/

Comment: You don't need the padding-right in ui-autocomplete, look http://jsfiddle.net/EVsye/83/ (:

Comment: Thanks this is working even in 2022 with jqueryui 1.13.0 and jquery 3.6.0. Only change I had to make is "self.menu.deactivate();" with "!this.active||(this.active.children("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover").removeAttr("id"),this._trigger("blur"),this.active=null)" as I am getting error that deactivate is not available

Answer (score 3):

Well even i wanted a solution to this question. 
Since there is not response i recommend you to check this post.
[jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox Very Slow With Large Select Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073612/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-very-slow-with-large-select-lists) 
They provide solutions but not ultimate answers
Anyways best of luck and if you do come up with a better solution,please post it here

Answer (score 1):

This example in Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/EVsye/ works good, but has one bug.

For example if you enter "a", then scroll down, then append to search "b", this will not show any results, as "ab" is not matching any results. Then if you backspace(delete) last character and the search string will be equal to "a", only first 5 results is shown and if you scroll down, nothing happens.

This is because window.pageIndex is not refreshed, as a fix when you create autocomplete, you should also specify "search" parameter like:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    search: function (event,ui) {
        window.pageIndex = 0;
    },
    source: availableTags,
```

and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a bit too late maybe for the answer. But searching for a similar component landed me on the following github page and it does the job perfectly. https://github.com/ashh640/Rich-Autocomplete

> A simple yet powerful autocomplete jQuery plugin. Very simply allows large lists of data, with custom rendering, paging, filtering and lazy loading with very little coding required.
> Complete with keyboard navigation for accessibility.

See several demos of Rich-Autocomplete in action here: http://beginninghere.co.uk/richautocomplete/example/