# jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox Menu Position slightly(incorrect) on IE10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, position, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image: 1st][image: 2nd]
  [image: 3rd]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jabavox/GVxQR/embedded/result/)

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6299156/818544) post. It's the best answer I've ever found (except you got better!? please show me),everything seems to be working great!(on ie9,ff,chrome) Until I face this issue(on ie10),every click on dropdown button make double increase position in suggestion menu!? This strange behavior occurs somehow instantly with large data source. Any idea? help me please...

Answer (score 0):

i think you need check `padding/margins` and eve better reset all these value with reset_css 
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/