# jQuery UI autocomplete gets very slow with long list of items

Tags: jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a list of around 8,000 items (loading from MySQL) and I made a simple HTML select field to load all of them but the load time was more than 10-15 seconds every time. Then i changed it to jQuery autocomplete which is much better than simple select field but the delay is still 8-10 seconds everytime. Is there any way to decrease the load time?

I try this method [jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox Very Slow With Large Select Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073612/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-very-slow-with-large-select-lists) but it doesn't affect the loading speed

Comment: I think the best solution to your problem would be to not load all 8000 items add once. Maybe you could implement some lazyloading for the items or take an approach which loads possible items based on your input from an API.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try html5 datalist

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

and you can also try light weight js http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

Comment: I followed the link but all examples are with very few items!? Is it really better performing? 8000 items are mentioned in the q.

Comment: Thanks for both hints anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem with datalist is that it currently cannot be styled... An astounding oversight by W3 designers.

Otherwise, it is faster than jq-ui autocomplete with thousands of list items.