# jQuery UI Autocomplete Multiple Values Very Slow With large lists

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I have a text box that searches name and emails. With the load, it can be extremely slow, as it was explained in [jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox Very Slow With Large Select Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073612/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-very-slow-with-large-select-lists)

Any ways to enhance the speed?

I had around 3000 emails.

Comment: Use AJAX and filter the data server-side instead of dumping it all in the DOM and trudging through it.

Comment: It is via the Google Contacts API, I am having trouble doing it

Comment: I have modified the Code. Can you check it now. Moreover API doesn't allow to get part by part via server side. aka to match all emails starting with say 'f'

Comment: In which case you don't have much of an alternative

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073612/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-very-slow-with-large-select-lists

Comment: Yes, although that doesn't work for jQueryUI 1.9+